# IOS NSDictionary element to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

Hi I am trying to extract key value from NSDictionary, the dictionary value looks like below screen shot

[image]

I need to extract the value with key "TITLE" to NSString, using the code

```
NSDictionary* tmp = [self getDBRequest:req];
NSString * title =[tmp valueForKey:@"TITLE"];
```

But giving the the value like

[image]

Is there anything wrong with above code?

**Edit:**

```
NSLog(@"%@", tmp);
```

Gives the output

```
2015-12-31 11:04:52.530 SimpleTable[610:10059] (
        {
        DESCRIPTION = "30% OFF ON NEW ";
        "IMAGE_URL" = "crowd.jpg";
        TITLE = "GET 30% OFF";
    }
)
```

**Edit2**

Actualy using the result of `NSString * title =[tmp valueForKey:@"TITLE"];` I have to replace an element of `NSMutableArray`

And the code

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [array addObject:@"Eezy"];
 [array addObject:@"Tutorials"];

 NSDictionary* tmp = [self getDBRequest:req];
 NSString * title =[tmp valueForKey:@"TITLE"];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:title];
```

Giving me the array modified some thing like below screen shot

[image]

Comment: can you tell us, what NSLog(@"%@", tmp); prints to the console?

Comment: And in what way is what you are getting not what you expected?

Comment: That code is working properly; although you want `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`.

Comment: @trojanfoe `objectForKey:` giving me an exception like `2015-12-31 11:15:11.297 SimpleTable[649:12131] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd09941a240'`

Comment: @FelixSFD Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Haris That doesn't make sense; are you sure it's on that line?  What you show is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: according to the output, you posted, it should work. As @trojanfoe said, this seems to be not a problem with the `NSDictionary`

Comment: Hi Please see my edited question.

Comment: So now you've changed the question completely.

Comment: @trojanfoe I modified the code as per suggestion `NSString * title =[tmp objectForKey:@"TITLE"];` and put the break point on same line and it gave exception when click stepover with the error message `2015-12-31 11:30:59.836 SimpleTable[720:15138] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f926240bab0
2015-12-31 11:30:59.840 SimpleTable[720:15138] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f926240bab0'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: @trojanfoe My final goal is to add/replace the value of an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first image in your question, the first line of the contents dump says "1 object".

Also look at the output of the `NSLog`, notice the parentheses (`(` & `)`) which *surround* the braces (`{` & `}`), which in turn surround the key/value pairs.

Both these are telling you that `tmp` is not referencing an `NSDictionary` as you think, but an `NSArray` containing a single element and that element is an `NSDictionary`.

Now when you invoke `valueForKey:` on an array of dictionaries it does the key lookup on every dictionary in the collection and returns and array of results.

Which is why when you look at the second image in your question you see that its contents dump also starts with "1 object" - `title` is referencing an array containing one element, being your string.

This is also why, as mentioned in the comments, that using `objectForKey:` in place of `valueForKey:` causes an error - that method does not operate on arrays and so produces the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.

HTH

Comment: You are right my data was something like explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311614/convert-json-to-nsarray  I changed the line `NSString * title =[tmp valueForKey:@"TITLE"];` to `NSArray *title = [tmp valueForKey:@"TITLE"];` and the issue solved. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score -3):

try like bellow code.

```
NSDictionary *tmp = @{@"DESCRIPTION" : @"30 OFF ON NEW",@"IMAGE_URL" : @"crowd.jpg",@"TITLE" : @"GET 30% OFF"};
//NSDictionary* tmp = [self getDBRequest:req];
NSArray *keyArray = [tmp allKeys];
NSString * title = [keyArray objectAtIndex:[keyArray indexOfObject:@"TITLE"]];//[keyArray objectAtIndex:0];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:title];
```

Comment: [temp allKeys] this return an NSArray of all keys of the dictionary 'temp' and [temp allValues] will return all values of the dictionary

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: he need 'key' of the dictionary

Comment: He has the key (`@"TITLE"`).  You have just demonstrated a random operation on an `NSDictionary`.  It doesn't help at all.